# Rails 4: association boolean in scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, scope

I've got a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship between two models and I want to write a scope to check if a boolean on the relationship is true:

```
class Component

  has_and_belongs_to_many :templates
  scope :editable, -> { where(template.showable) }

  ....
end
```

On the `Template` model `:showable` is a boolean. How can I write this in Rails 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scope :editable, -> { joins(:templates).where( templates: { showable: true } ) }
```

Comment: Well that was easy. Cheers!